# Vue "ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, babelify

I am trying to import a node module into my Vue project and am getting the following error:

```
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I understand that this is probably due to the node module not being transformed by babelify but I am not sure how to fix it.

My code can be found here:

https://github.com/timothyylim/vue-date-picker-example

Running

```
npm install 
npm run dev
```

should show the error. I simply started with the [vue-cli browserify template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify) and tried to pull in [a date picker component](https://github.com/weifeiyue/vue-datepicker-local).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess I'm too late for this one, after posting the edit to my answer realise you were the one that opened the ticket on the data-picker component.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Follow the readme of the project you linked and use `vue-cli`: ~</s>

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init browserify my-project
cd my-project
npm install
npm run dev
```

Follow up the command-line instructions, I had to install also `@vue/cli-init` as suggested. By the time being this worked, I can see the vue-cli compiles the same example you pointed out.

**EDIT:**

Looks like this was a issue with the component [weifeiyue/vue-datepicker-local](https://github.com/weifeiyue/vue-datepicker-local), it was recently fixed here:

https://github.com/weifeiyue/vue-datepicker-local/commit/a6e3078936a37acc1d6344b7b4d8c14b42be0844

The solution should be as simple as update the component.

Answer (score 0):

This error came up for me in an already Vue 3 working project. There was no apparent reason as everything worked okay before this issue.

I added the type key to the package.json to enforce the build process, using CommonJs as vue.config.js is in this format.

```json
{
  "type": "commonjs"
}
```

Then from the terminal:

```bash
npm ci
```

---

If it still does not work. I would delete the package-lock.json, remove the node_modules directory then reinstall.
Ultimately, I took this step, but it should not be necessary.